# Cannot read property 'error' of null jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of null" during datatable loading. The following is the code to ajax call and populate the table. The error seems to be internal in jquery datatable. How can i check the null in the returned ajax response

```js
table = $('#data-table').DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            responsive: true,
            serverSide: false,
            autoWidth: false,
            paging: true,
            filter: true,
            searching: true,
            stateSave: true,
            scrollX: true,
            displayLength: 10,
            language: {
                "search": "Filtrer: "
            },
            ajax: {
                url: '/Observer/GetActiveClientsByFloor',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    FloorId: floorId,
                    TypeId: typeId
                },
                dataSrc: ''
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    title: 'Zone',
                    data: 'LastKnownZone',
                },
                {
                     title: 'SSID',
                     data: 'ssId',
                },
                {
                    title: 'Status',
                    data: 'Statut',
                },
             
            ],
            
            createdRow: (row, data, dataIndex, cells) => 
            {

                const selectedRowProfileId = $('#selectedRowProfileId', window.parent.document).val();

                

                }
            },

            initComplete: function (settings, json) {

                clients = json;
                console.log(clients);
                if (clients.length !== 0) {

                    clients.forEach(client => {

                       


                    });

                }

            }
        }).order([[1, 'asc']]).draw(false);
```

Comment: If pressing the F12 button and looking at the ajax call inside the dev console is not enough, try testing the ajax call separately from the table, so you can check the data is ok before you try to create a table from it.

Comment: It seemed that my ajax call had the exceptions.